# SQL query with Unicode character in the middle

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question to update issue with unicode character -

character `á` has unicode `U+00E0`
But how to do it in the middle of String?

```
update `table` set 
`column` = "String with á sign in the middle"
where
`Column` = .......
```

How does the string with unicode á look like?

Thanks

Comment: can you submit your complete query

Comment: let say -  I would  like to put "String with á sign in the middle"
this á - how to do it with Unicode?

Comment: UPDATE `test`.`test` SET `name` = 'String with á sign in the middle' WHERE `test`.`name` = '33333' LIMIT 1 ; this is working fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL unicode literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632410/mysql-unicode-literals)

Comment: hi Marcus, Iam able to write á as ASCII, but it doesn´t work :(

Comment: Then see this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send this query before your main query:(for setting the connection charset)

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'") or die();
```

it's maybe helping you.

Comment: Maybe stupid question - Isnt there  no possibility  to put \U+00E0 instead of á sign ?  e.g. "String with \U+00E0 sign in the middle"

Comment: I know it,Do you want I delete my Answer??

Comment: You can if you want :)

Comment: [MySQL documentations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_database) says you shouldn't set `character_set_database` directly.