# How to Replace hidden white space Character in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have to replace the hidden white space character in ' 331431'.
The hidden *white space character* in this string was `'\u00A0'`.
How to replace this character with mysql?

I have tried the usual replace mysql function to replace this, didn't work for me.

```
SELECT REPLACE(' 331431','\u00A0','');
```

The Output for the above Query is `' 331431'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL unicode literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632410/mysql-unicode-literals)

Comment: Try `SELECT REPLACE(' 331431', x'C2A0', '');`

Comment: How did you know that the hidden character is `\u00A0`?

Comment: thank you for your response, I have checked from the following website https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php